# Programmatically index non-JSON documents for Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: python, indexing, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-services

I would like to programmatically do what an Azure indexer does, that pushes documents from a data source to an index on Azure. Ideally written in Python.

It could be done via an Azure indexer but I would like to handle this pushing logic on my own.

The documents are of various formats, most commonly `docx, pdf, pptx`.

Assume an Azure index already exists, and the documents are retrievable within this custom indexer's reach.

I would like to do something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-optimize-indexing-push-api), which includes pushing the documents with very custom batch sizes, frequencies, multithreading strategies.

So far I only know how to push JSON format data, which can be done via a Python Azure SDK call

```
def add_doc(docs):
    search_client = SearchClient(ENDPOINT, index_name, AzureKeyCredential(KEY))
    result = search_client.upload_documents(documents=docs)
    print("Upload of new document succeeded: {}".format(result[0].succeeded))
```

where `docs` is defined as a list of dictionaries:

```
doc1 = {
  'field1': xxx,
  'field2': yyy,
  'field3': zzz
}
docs = [doc1, doc2, doc3, ...]
```

However, in real application, I would want to be able to push an entire file of the aforementioned types including but not limited to `docx, pdf, pptx`.

I cannot find official support for indexing non-JSON files.
The `upload_documents()` method only works for list of dict:

```
upload_documents(documents: List[dict], **kwargs: Any) -> List[IndexingResult]
```

Here are some possibilities I am thinking:

1. Somehow convert the arbitrary files into JSON, by extracting the text from within via some Python libraries. The robustness of such approach is very uncertain. Files of size larger than a normal transferable JSON can also lead to stitching complications.
2. Hopefully there exists some API calls for transferring files in binary format. Decoding can be done at the custom indexer side and custom skillset applied to such files. Then encoding back and pushed to an Azure index.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information one possible solution is to push non-JSON files like docx, pdf, and pptx to an Azure index with the use of **Azure Files indexer** (Preview). This indexer can extract text from various document formats and make it searchable in Azure Cognitive Search.

Below are some of the relevant document format supports by Azure File Indexer:

- CSV
- Microsoft Office formats: DOCX/DOC/DOCM, XLSX/XLS/XLSM,
  PPTX/PPT/PPTM, MSG (Outlook emails),
- XML
- PDF
- Plain text files
- ZIP

As of now, the service is available as public preview, and you can use it via **REST API** with `python and request package`.

For details regarding setup and configuration you can check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-file-storage-integration)

Comment: The "Azure Files indexer" appears to be the same or similar thing as the [Azure Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-overview) already mentioned in this post. I know of its existence, have used it, and it is not what I want. I want to programmatically replace it.